# How to say this more naturally?

Tags: word-choice

"While speaking, I rush a lot and don't breathe at all. When I run out of breath, I take in a long breath creating that annoying breathing sound".

How to express this in fewer sentences that sound more natural? Is there a verb or phrase for this phenomenon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps "I have difficulty coordinating my speech with my breathing"?